# How can I get the V-I characteristics of negative resistor of Chua diode

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, transistors, capacitor, resistors

I want to simulate the Chua circuit in which a negative resistor is used. I want to simulate the V-I characteristics of Chua diode. But it does not get the same result as shown in book or papers. please help me to find out error in this circuit.[image] And also i am not get voltage across v3 option in add trace i only get option I(V3)  [image]

sir, i did not get how can i plot V-I graph from this circuit. i want this curve shown in fig 3.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *please help me to find out error in this circuit*

The double red-boxed item is surely an error. The single red-boxed item is potentially an error: -

[image]

---

You also don't seem to have this connection on your [schematic](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Robust-OP-Amp-Realization-of-Chua%27s-Circuit-Kennedy/38b98ab3a2a0900e9eefdfa2d86bf6db17675419): -

[image]

In other words, the 2nd op-amp circuit on the right is not being driven by your signal V3. Maybe you copied the circuit from [this erroneous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/447302/how-to-work-out-this-implementation-of-chuas-diode)?

> *I am not get voltage across v3 option in add trace*

That node is probably one listed as V(n001) to V(n010). If you explicitly label the node, it will appear in the add trace list I expect.

Comment: After correcting this i do not get the same result. And how can I get the V3 on the x-axis instead of I(V3). In Add trace option i am getting only this options, only I(V3) is given

Comment: I don't use LTspice so, now that the specific question has been answered, ask a new question about arranging the axes you speak about. I'm sure others will contribute rather than leaving your comment lingering hear where not so many will comment. Make sure you tag LTspice in your new question and make sure you put a comparison picture of what you do get that is different to the results of what you should get @UshaKumari

Comment: Try adding a node label to the node you want to display in the analysis. That node is probably one already listed in the table in your edited question.